# IDE marks Listener in red and says the it is not abstract

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

What is wrong in this code?:
When I declare the ***private class Listener implements ActionListener*** the IDE marks just Listener in red and says the it is not abstract

```
package hello;  
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class hello{

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel title;
    private JPanel mainPanel;

    public hello(){
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        hello helloo = new hello();
        helloo.Event();
    }

    private void prepareGUI(){
        mainFrame = new JFrame("This is a test project");
        mainFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        title = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);

        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
        mainFrame.add(title);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void Event(){
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Test");
        button1.setSize(15,10);
        button1.setActionCommand("Test");
        button1.addActionListener(new Listener());

        mainPanel.add(button1);

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class Listener implements ActionListener{
        public void action(ActionEvent e){
            String com = e.getActionCommand();
            if(com.equals("Test")){
                title.setText("button clicked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am very new at JAVA, started yesterday, so any recommendations will be helpful
P.S. I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.4

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not the whole error message. You could start by reading the whole error and understanding what it says.

Comment: And please switch to using a real IDE that will automatically fix this for you.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't implemented the required methods for the `ActionListener` interface.

Somewhere in that class, fill it with:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    // Fill
}
```

You have an `action(ActionEvent)` method, but that is spelled wrong.

Answer (score 3):

you have not implemented `actionPerformed()` method

do this

```
@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

When you are implementing some interface then you need to override all the methods

After adding the required codes,It will look like this

```
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class hello{

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel title;
    private JPanel mainPanel;

    public hello(){
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        hello helloo = new hello();
        helloo.Event();
    }

    private void prepareGUI(){
        mainFrame = new JFrame("This is a test project");
        mainFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        title = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);

        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
        mainFrame.add(title);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void Event(){
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Test");
        button1.setSize(15,10);
        button1.setActionCommand("Test");
        button1.addActionListener(new Listener());

        mainPanel.add(button1);

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class Listener implements ActionListener{
        public void action(ActionEvent e){
            String com = e.getActionCommand();
            if(com.equals("Test")){
                title.setText("button clicked");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { // this method you need to ovverride
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code change **action** to **actionPerformed** since the interface `ActionListener` has the method `actionPerformed(..)` not `action(..)`

```
private class Listener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String com = e.getActionCommand();
            if(com.equals("Test")){
                title.setText("button clicked");
            }
    }
    }
```